# Difficulty proving that if set of vectors v's span doesn't contain another vector b, then the set of vectors v & vector b isn't linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having trouble proving the following problem:

> Let $A$ be a vector space over a field $F$. If the set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\} \subset A$ is defined as a generating set which does not include a vector $b \in A$, then $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n, b\}$ is **not** linearly independent.

From my understanding, the set of vectors is linearly dependent if at least one of the vectors in the set can be written as a linear combination of the other vectors in the set. From the problem description, it seems clear to me that vector $b$ cannot be written as a linear combination of the other vectors in the set $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$, since it is not within $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$'s span. However, how do I now prove that the set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ is linearly dependent? I didn't find enough information in the question to figure this out.

Comment: In this context, "include" means "has as an element of the set." If $u,v$ are two distinct non-zero vectors, then the set $\{u,v\}$ **includes** just the two vectors $u$ and $v.$ It does not **include** $u+v,$ $u-v$, $2u$, $-v$, or any of the other vectors in the span of $\{u,v\}$ aside from $u$ and $v$ themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be with the framing of the problem. Let's break it down. First, we have that $\{v_1,...,v_n\}\subset A$ be defined as a generating set. This implies that $\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}=A$. Now we are told that the set of vectors does not contain $b$, so we have that $b\notin\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, but we will have that $b\in A$. Now to see that $\{v_1,...,v_n,b\}$ is linearly dependent it suffices to show that there is a non-trivial linear combination giving $0$. As $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a generating set of $A$, given any $w\in A$ there exist $c_i\in F$ such that $\sum c_iv_i=w$, so as $b\in A$ there exist $c_i\in F$ such that $\sum c_iv_i=b$, then we have that $(\sum c_iv_i)-b=0$ is a non-trivial linear combination of zero from the set $\{v_1,...,v_n,b\}$, so we have that this is a linearly dependent set.

Comment: Long story short, I think it is more of a phrasing issue, you will have that $b\in\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, but you are requiring that $b\notin\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, so $\{v_1,...,v_n,b\}$ is linearly dependent.